# How to count employees who are involved in a proct and list there names in one cell?

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to write a query which shows me the number of employees who are involved in a project and also list there names in just one cell.

```
select p.projectname, count(main.projectnr) "Involved employees" from projects_karl p
join mainpro_karl main
on main.projectnr = p.projectnr
join employees_karl m
on m.employeenr = main.employeenr
group by p.beschreibung
;
```

This query counts the amount of employees who are working in a certain project. 
But I also want to list the names of the involved employees.

```
select p.projectname, count(main.projectnr) "Anzahl beteiligter MAs", m.firstname || ' ' || m.surname "Name" from projects_karl p
join mainpro_karl main
on main.projectnr = p.projectnr
join Employees_karl m
on m.employeenr = main.employeenr
group by p.projectname, m.firstname || ' ' || m.surname
;
```

This query list involved employees but not in a cell but in a own row. And the count function does not works anymore. It just counts '1' in every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `listagg()`

```
select p.projectname, count(main.projectnr) "Anzahl beteiligter MAs", 
listagg(m.firstname || ' ' || m.surname, ',') within group (order by p.projectname) "Name" 
from projects_karl p join mainpro_karl main on main.projectnr = p.projectnr
join Employees_karl m on m.employeenr = main.employeenr
group by p.projectname
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I need @fa06 ^^ Thank you very much!

Comment: ok I will! I have to wait for 5 minutes and then I am able to accept you answer. Thanks a lot again :)